# Pass Object Via Command Line For PHP

Tags: php, command-line

I'm trying to execute a php script from inside another script. The the first script's output doesn't depend on the second script, and the second script takes a while to execute, so I'm using the exec command in the first script to run the second script and appending the line with an ampersand to make the second script run in the background.

```
exec('php /path/to/secondScript.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &');
```

I know there are inherent security risks with using the exec command. I'm fine with that for now since I'm not using any user inputs.

My problem is I want to pass the object $object to the second script. How can I do that? I tried:

```
exec('php /path/to/secondScript.php $object > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &');
```

And using in the second script:

```
$argv[0];
```

But it's returning as null.

I tried modifying the exec line, without luck, to:

```
exec("php /path/to/secondScript.php $object > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");
```

But that made the script fail.

Since $object is an object, do I need to turn it into a string first?

Comment: yes you need to convert into the string by serializing the object using `$object = serialize($object);`

Comment: Thanks, that definitely seems to help. I changed it to `$objectString = serialize($object); 
exec('php /path/to/secondScript.php '.$objectString.' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &');` It works if $object is a string like 'test' but doesn't run if $object is a big multidimensional object.

Comment: it will work even if it's the large object ,show us the sample of object which you are trying to execute

Answer (score -1):

Serialize the object into string and then try

```
$object = serialize($object);
exec("php /path/to/secondScript.php $object > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");
```